# Markov chain property

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I would like to make clarification and show my curiosity about markov process. I will show some  part of definition related to markov process from [here](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jtc5/251/stochastic-processes.pdf).

The Markov property is the dependence structure among random variables. The simplest dependence structure for $X_0, X_1, . . .$ is no dependence at all, that is, independence.

The Markov property could be said to capture the next simplest sort of dependence: in generating the process $X_0, X_1, . . . $sequentially, the “next” state $X_{n+1}$  depends only on the “current” value $X_n$, and not on the “past” values

$$X_0, . . ., X_{n−1}$$

while statement itself seems clear. I am curiosity about one thing: we are saying that next state depend only on current state, but on the other hand current state is the same as next state for one step previous process, right?

$X_2$ is depend on $X_1$,not on $X_0$, but $X_1$ is depend on $X_0$  and so on, so how is cancelled this dependence effect as we move forward? How dependence between $X_0$ and $X_2$ lost?

Comment: I suggest to use the "shift" key as it is needed, it has a much better effect for your writing quality as it seems.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @PeterHorvath Your "in memoriam Augeas" made my day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Markov chain property does not say that $X_0$ and $X_2$ are independent, only that the dependence of $X_2$ on $(X_0,X_1)$ is equivalent to the (a priori simpler) dependence of $X_2$ on $X_1$ only.

Consider for example some i.i.d. standard normal random variables $Z_k$ and define
$$
(X_0,X_1,X_2)=(Z_0,Z_0+Z_1,Z_0+Z_1+Z_2).
$$
Then $(X_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant2}$ is a Markov chain because $X_2=X_1+Z$ where $Z=Z_2$ is independent of $(X_0,X_1)$ and standard normal. Thus, the conditional distribution of $X_2$ conditionally on $(X_0,X_1)$ is normal with mean $X_1$ and variance $1$, in particular this conditional distribution depends on $(X_0,X_1)$ through $X_1$ only, as Markov property demands.

And $X_2=X_0+Y$ where $Y=Z_1+Z_2$ is independent of $X_0$ and centered normal with variance $2$ hence the conditional distribution of $X_2$ conditionally on $X_0$ is normal with mean $X_0$ and variance $2$, in particular this conditional distribution does depend on $X_0$.

Comment: so can we  say like this that in Markov process when next state is depend on current and not past simple it means that this past is already  contained in current and we dont need to consider any more for next state analysis?

Comment: Yes. The dependence of the future on the past and the present is already contained in the dependence of the future on the present alone. One often finds the phrase that "the future and the past are independent conditionally on the present", which is equivalent.